# Can we set a text as watermark in jw player 6

Tags: jwplayer

I'm having a doubt about the setting up of a watermark in jwplayer 6.
Is there is any possibility of setting a text as watermark instead of logo, as given in there documentation url.
[Here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28841/branding-your-player/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watermark can only be an image. One thing you could do is make a transparent PNG image that is just text in PhotoShop (or any other image editing program), and use that as the watermark image, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "/assets/myVideo.mp4",
    height: 360,
    image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg",
    logo: {
        file: '/assets/myLogo.png',
        link: 'http://example.com'
    },
    width: 640
});
```

http://www.phpsugar.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=10577

Answer (score 0):

You can set a dynamic watermark using a script and a .htaccess file.
You need to create a png image (which can be either opaque or transparent).
Call it watermark.png for instance. 
Then write a script, like this:

```
<?php
$text="Whatever text you want";
$im = imagecreate($imagewidth, 50);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 200, 200, 200);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 5, 3, $text, $textcolor);

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png',true,200);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Safe the file a watermark.php for example.
Then, in order to make it work in JWplayer, you fill in:

```
logo: {
    file: 'watermark.png',
    link: 'http://example.com'
},
```

Then create a .htacces file like this to automatically load the script instead of the watermark.png in the JWplayer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)watermark.png$ watermark.php [L]
```

I hope that helps?